# Efficient way to find the maximum velocity for each date

Tags: r

I have a large list composed of multiple data-frames that look like the one below.

```
    ls.DataFrame[[1]]
    Date            Velocity
    10/1/1990           5.5
    10/1/1990           5.5
    10/1/1990           5.5
    10/1/1990           5.2
    10/1/1990           5.2
    10/1/1990           5.2
    10/2/1990           5.2
    10/2/1990           5.2
    10/2/1990           5.2
    10/2/1990           5.2
    10/2/1990           5
    10/2/1990           5.2
    10/2/1990           5.2
    10/3/1990           4.2
    10/3/1990           4.2
    10/3/1990           4.2
    10/3/1990           4.4
    10/3/1990           4.2
    10/3/1990           3.7
    10/3/1990           3.7
```

My desired output is to keep the date and the maximum velocity for that specific date. Here is what I would want the output to look like

```
    Date            Velocity
    10/1/1990           5.5
    10/2/1990           5.2
    10/3/1990           4.4
```

I tried doing this but does not work properly

```
    max(ls.Dataframe[[1]]Velocity[ls.dataframe[[1]]$Date]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop over the `list` with `map`, grouped by 'Date', get the `max` of 'Velocity' with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(ls.Dataframe, ~ .x %>%
                      group_by(Date) %>%
                      summarise(Velocity = max(Velocity))
```

Or with `data.table` to do it more efficiently

```
library(data.table)
lapply(ls.Dataframe, function(x) 
     as.data.table(x)[, .(Velocity = max(Velocity)), by = Date])
```

---

In `base R`, we loop with `lapply` and use `aggregate`, but it would be slow

```
lapply(ls.Dataframe, function(x) aggregate(Velocity ~ Date, x, FUN = max))
```

Comment: Is `aggregate` that much slower than `dplyr::group_by`/`summarise`? I would have expected it to be roughly the same in performance.

Comment: @r2evans  `aggregate` is slower from some benchmarks I did in the past.  Donno, if it is very fast in the new version

Comment: I am getting the following error trying the solution proposed below: no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "Date"

Comment: @ChristopherMontalvo  I can't reproduce that behavior.  As far as I know, Date class gels well with `dplyr`

Comment: For some reason, Dates was being entered as a class character, instead of class Date. Thanks it works perfectly.

Comment: @ChristopherMontalvo  The format of `Date` showeed in your example is not the `Date` class format.  It needs to be converted to the format with `map(ls.Dataframe, ~ .x %>% group_by(Date = dmy(Date)) %>%` assuming that it is day/month/year format